# why php echo does not work in windows version firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

my php code in wordpress site as follows:

```
<div id="contact-tel">
     <h2>Tel: <?php echo the_field('phone', 17); ?></h2>    <!-- Windows version firefox does not display echo-->
</div>
```

I noticed in windows version firefox (not sure the version number of FF) does not display the telephone number after Tel: word. It just show Tel:

if I add some words before echo then it displays, also i noticed, while page finishes loading, Tel number shows and then hide quickly.

[site location](http://new.saffronresourcing.com)

Does anybody have any idea ?

Comment: PHP runs on server side and will not change its behaviour with different browsers. What does the final, generated HTML code look like?

Comment: Indeed. A browser can't affect `echo` (though it may render the result in differing ways under certain conditions). You have a mistake somewhere else... most likely in CSS or Javascript. Also "not sure the version number" isn't very useful: find out.

Comment: If it shows and then hides quickly, it's either CSS or Javascript doing the hiding (the element is displaying for the time it takes either a stylesheet to load or some Javascript to run that hides it.) This is definitely not a PHP problem.

Comment: the site that you rpovided works fine and the phone number is displayed.

Comment: Works fine on FF5, maybe you have Skype or another type of plugin which tries to parse the phone number?

Comment: @Anne/Tomalak a slight rearrangement ... FWIW FF5 WFM.  Along those lines, FWIW FF4 WFM!

Answer (score 5):

I think I know what is going on, as I've seen this before.

Do you happen to have Skype installed? This installs a Firefox plugin which tries to detect phone numbers on web pages and makes them clickable, but often fails. Try disabling this addon and your phone number will show.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove div and h2 tags and see if it displays. PHP works on the server side and has nothing to do with browser version.

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing WordPress web site locally on Mac, and I have similar issue. But, for my part `echo` work well on all browser. Only on my function with `get_posts()` that can not work on Safari and Firefox.

In my case, I try to echo out the list of bloggers form my template part content-blogger.php to index.php.

```
<aside class="row som-blog-author" aria-labelledby="som-blog-authors">

<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2 id="som-blog-authors">
        Blogger
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>


<ul class="col-xs-12 som-blog-authors-list">

    <?php

        $som_authors = som_get_cat_authors( 'blog' );

        foreach ($som_authors as &$som_author) :

            $blog_author_name  = get_userdata( $som_author )->display_name;
            $blog_author_url   = get_author_posts_url( $som_author );

            echo '
            <li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <a href="' . $blog_author_url . '">' . $blog_author_name . '</a>
            </li>
            ';

        endforeach;

    ?>

</ul><!-- .som-blog-authors-list -->

</aside><!-- .som-blog-author -->
```

I used function `som_get_cat_authors()` to create array of author's ids and echo out in `foreach` loop above. This function also didn't work on Firefox and Safari. I used `var_dump($som_authors);` to check the variable but it return `null`. But on chrome, it work perfectly.

```
function som_get_cat_authors( $cat ) {

    if ( is_category( $cat ) ) {

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'category_name'  => $cat,
            'orderby'        => 'author',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
        );

        $cat_posts = get_posts( $args );

        $user_posts = array();

        foreach( $cat_posts as &$cat_post ) {

            $user_posts[] = $cat_post->post_author;

        }

        $author_id_array = array_unique( $user_posts );

        return $author_id_array;

    }

}
```

ps. `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` show on three browsers